# Building a view from the server - AJAX, JAVA EE

Tags: java, ajax, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm making one application using Ajax for different views, and this views has different URLs for example: http://example.com/view1 & http://example.com/view2, is working well, the problem is when I put the URL into the navigator and click enter, obviously I am getting the Json written on the screen, so there are any possibility to call the function of JavaScript that build the view or directly the success method in the Ajax petition?

OK, I'll try to explain it a little better so, imagine that we have two Ajax calls like that:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/view1',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#view2').hide();
        $('#view1').show();
        ....... do something in the view 1 with the data.
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/view2',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#view1').hide();
        $('#view2').show();
        ....... do something in the view 2 with the data.
    }
});
```

This is working well if we are doing this Ajax calls, but when we put the URL address directly into the navigation browser, I am getting the Json data written on the screen like is correct, so the question is, there are any possibility to execute the success method when we put the URL address directly into the navigator browser?

Thanks.

Comment: i am not quite sure what do you mean. Can you please rephrase the question, or explain it a little bit further?

Comment: OK, I've tried to explain it a little bit better. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put directly the URL in the browser, then the `get` method of your servlet is called.

Therefore in your servlet, you can keep your `doPost()` functionality, but you can add some functionality on the `doGet()` method. In the `doGet()` you can display directly the current view and initialize any other code in a `$( document ).ready()`.